# PowerShell add text line to multiple files

Tags: powershell

Powershell experince 3 hours...

Scenario: need to add a line of code to the top of multiple ASPX files in multiple folders and subfolders

Is this possible?

I've figured out how to search for the files but adding that line of code is where I'm stuck.
This is what I have, which is not working

```
Get-ChildItem C:\domain_3 -recurse -include "*.aspx" |
Foreach-Object { 
    Add-Content -Path $targetFile -Value "<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="LandingPages.LandingPage" %>"; 
}
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 6):

```
$header=@"
"<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="LandingPages.LandingPage" %>
"@

Get-ChildItem C:\domain_3 -Recurse -Filter *.aspx | Foreach-Object { 
    $header`n" + (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( I can't test it now)

Create a function:

```
function Insert-Content ($file) {
BEGIN {
$content = Get-Content $file
}
PROCESS {
$_ | Set-Content $file
}
END {
$content | Add-Content $file
}
}
```

then use it:

```
(dir c:\domain_3 -r -filter *.txt ) | % { '<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="LandingPages.LandingPage" %>' | insert-content $_.fullname }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works [Not very sure about the encoding part]

```
$file="F:\Default2.aspx"
$content = Get-Content $file
$content = "<%@ Page Language=`"C#`" Inherits=`"LandingPages.LandingPage`" %>" + $content;
Set-Content $file $content
```