# Add text to multiple files via powershell

Tags: powershell, text, coding-style

I am trying to customise the code described here [PowerShell add text line to multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162939/powershell-add-text-line-to-multiple-files) 
to my case. I have multiple csv files with numbers only and on the first line I would like to have a specific phrase (e.g catchment rainfall file). 
I am doing the following: 
>

```
$header=@"
>"catchment rainfall
>"@

>Get-ChildItem D:\Documents and Settings\mary\testing\mary00 -Recurse -Filter *.aspx | >Foreach-Object { 
>    $header`n" + (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName"
>}
```

Any thoughts on where I am going wrong? 
Thanks so much.

Comment: what is the error ? BTW verify the code : in begining of line 2 you have a `"` . Your code seems ok elsewhere... What is the output when you remove  `|Set-Content` ?

Comment: humm.. in the foreach-object seem there's problem with `"`

Comment: The error is: Unexpected token '`n" + (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -P
ath $_.FullName"' in expression or statement.
At line:2 char:86 
+  $header`n" + (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $_.F
ullName" <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (`n" + (Get-Cont...th $_.FullName":
   String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: I also wanted to mention that on the first post, where *.aspx, I actually have  *.csv but I dont think this is the issue.

Comment: tried this but still doesn't work :( : $header=@"catchment rainfall"@ Get-ChildItem D:\Documents and Settings\mary\testing\mary00 -Recurse -Filter *.csv | >Foreach-Object { $header`n + (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName }

Comment: i think it's only a typo :  
`$header=@"
catchment rainfall
"@ 
Get-ChildItem "D:\Documents and Settings\mary\testing\mary00" -Recurse -Filter *.csv| Foreach-Object { $header+"`n"+ (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName -whatif}`

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone for their help. I have finally come up with this which works:

```
$header=@"
catchment rainfall
"@ 
Get-ChildItem .\testing\ -Recurse -Filter *.csv| Foreach-Object { $header+"`n"+ (Get-Content $_.FullName | Out-String) | Set-Content -Path $_.FullName}
```